# HAProxy read a cookie from request and re-assign it as a custom header

Tags: haproxy

I am receiving a JWT token as part of the `Cookie` from an auth service.

`Cookie: "jwt_token=eyBGfdr..................."`

Now, I need to read that cookie within HAProxy, extract the `jwt_token` key and add a custom header called `jwt_token` and assign the value `eyBGfdr` and finally forward the request to some other service.

I have figured out a part of the solution using the `http-request set-header` directive but I am not sure how to read the cookie and store it in a variable to use with the `set-header` directive.

Additional Explanation:
My haproxy sits between an auth server and a web service. The auth server creates a JWT token and inserts that as a cookie. But, the web service on the other side can only read JWT using custom headers. Hence, I am trying to make my haproxy work in a way such that it can intercept the JWT token from the cookie and put it in the custom header so that the web service can also read it.

Comment: I suspect you are missing a detail, here.  You can't return a redirect to send the browser elsewhere and then expect the browser to do something involving a request header. Similarly, if you `http-request set-header ...` and then emit a redirect, that header goes nowhere.  HTTP has no mechanism for the kind of behavior you appear to be describing.  The only way to pass payload on a redirect is in the query string.  So, we need some clarificarion of what you are trying to do and exactly the behavior that is required.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot My haproxy sits between an auth server and a web service. The auth server creates a JWT token and inserts that as a cookie. But, the web service on the other side can only read JWT using custom headers. Hence, I am trying to make my haproxy work in a way such that it can intercept the JWT token from the cookie and put it in the custom header so that the web service can also read it.

Comment: So when you said *redirect*, you must have meant *forward*.  A redirect is an `HTTP 30x` response that tells the browser to go make a request somewhere else.

Comment: yeah, you are correct! sorry about my poor terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

haproxy.conf

```
global
    debug
frontend web1
    bind *:8080
    mode http
    default_backend app1
backend app1
    mode http
    http-request set-header jwt %[req.cook(jwt_token)]
    server s1 127.0.0.1:8000
```

haproxy version

```
Nuster version 1.8.8.2.2
Copyright (C) 2017-2018, Jiang Wenyuan, <koubunen AT gmail DOT com >

HA-Proxy version 1.8.8.2 2018/05/29
Copyright 2000-2018 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>
```

server.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import logging
import time

PORT = 8000

class GetHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        logging.error(self.headers)
        SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

Handler = GetHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

curl

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/xxx --cookie "jwt_token=asdf"

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /xxx HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: jwt_token=asdf
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.10
```

server.py log:

```
User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
Accept: */*
Cookie: jwt_token=asdf
jwt: asdf

127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jun/2018 13:30:19] "GET /xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: yes, but you can also use  `lua-load /any/path/cookie.lua`

Comment: @summerNight updated, you need to build haproxy with lua support. lua version depends on your OS though, this should work on `ubuntu:xenial`,  you can also install lua by your self like this: https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/docker-nuster/blob/master/alpine/Dockerfile

Comment: @summerNight sorry, use the simple solution. I'm too keen to lua recently

Comment: I still dont see the header
➜  dev curl -i --cookie "jwt_token=myJWT" -XGET http://127.0.0.1:8000/web1
HTTP/1.0 404 File not found
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.10
Date: Fri, 08 Jun 2018 02:08:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html

<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 404.
<p>Message: File not found.
<p>Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
</body>

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked like a charm! Very simple and easy to follow :)